# Flutter: Time interval not working as expected

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to do something after every 2 seconds so i used this code :

```
Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
     print(DateTime.now());
   });
```

but i am getting this result which is not expected:

```
I/flutter ( 3289): 2020-10-12 21:22:43.670760
I/flutter ( 3289): 2020-10-12 21:22:44.775357
I/flutter ( 3289): 2020-10-12 21:22:48.648645
I/flutter ( 3289): 2020-10-12 21:22:49.777089
I/flutter ( 3289): 2020-10-12 21:22:53.648152
I/flutter ( 3289): 2020-10-12 21:22:54.776803
I/flutter ( 3289): 2020-10-12 21:22:58.648512
I/flutter ( 3289): 2020-10-12 21:22:59.775297
I/flutter ( 3289): 2020-10-12 21:23:03.647867
I/flutter ( 3289): 2020-10-12 21:23:04.775481
```

My full code

```
class test extends StatelessWidget {
  var i ;
  time(){
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {

      print(DateTime.now());
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    time();
    return Container();
  }
}
```

as you can see i wanted to print the time in the interval of 5 seconds but its doing something else. I have no idea why, Can someone please tell me what should i do to meet my expectation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `https://fluttermaster.com/tips-to-use-timer-in-dart-and-flutter/` check this out it might help @D. Go.

Comment: what is the function `debugPrint` ? Can you paste its code,

Comment: @Assassin i checked it and i have updated my issue, please have a look at it and thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: thanks for your interest @JackShen,  i have updated my issue, hope it will help you understand my problem :)

Comment: run flutter clean and run again,@D. Go.

Comment: You have somehow started the timer twice. Are you creating the timer in a `build` method?

Comment: @Assassin didnt work :(

Comment: @RichardHeap i created a function for the timer but i am calling the function from build method, I have updated the issue with whole code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run flutter clean and uninstall previous app,then run again

```
@override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (timer) {
          print(DateTime.now());
        });
      }
```

working example

[image: Screenshot]